# Where can I find Liferay themes (_styled and classic) in JSP?

Tags: jsp, liferay, velocity, liferay-theme

When I generate a Liferay Plugin for a Theme using JSP in Liferay's IDE, the project doesn't generate any JSP files. 
When I do it with Velocity or Freemarker, the SDK creates generates all the templates (portal_normal.vm, portlet.vm) when I run ant. This doesn't happen with JSP. I tried to merge it or build it but all the JSP are missing.

I looked for the JSP version of the _styled or classic themes ([or any theme at all](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-plugins/tree/master/themes)) to use them as a base to create mine, but I don't find any complete theme which uses JSP instead of Velocity or Freemarker. No portal_normal.jsp nor portlet.jsp descriptions out there.

I need to use JSP files directly, not importing them on Velocity templates. Is this possible?

Where can I see a reference to create Themes using only JSP (no Velocity nor Freemarker)?

Comment: I think Liferay is used velocity for classic and _styled.

Comment: Is there any official basic theme that uses JSP?

Comment: No Idea!, why do you prefer jsp?

Comment: Client requirements. Some people is just not ready to give up on JSP and the comfort of the known.

Comment: ok, can I talk to you? see my profile